# Where to activate my proxy setting in my django app

Tags: python, django, proxy

I am trying send an activation mail to the users in my django app. I am developing in my company and it has proxy. So, when i try to send email to the user, it gives connection timeout error. But when i try it in my home it works perfectly. I have got the proxy settings from my company but I am confused where to update the proxy settings for my django app. Any help on how to make this work ?

Comment: http://django-http-proxy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html this might help.

Comment: @Aditya This has nothing to do with accessing an email server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to use HTTP proxy to access external SMTP server.
It is feasible if your proxy server supports Socks or CONNECT methods.
Consider using this libraries to wrap your smtp-related code:

1. http://socksipy.sourceforge.net/
2. https://gist.github.com/frxstrem/4487802